# Which Schema.org type should be used for webinars?

Tags: schema.org

I’m looking to improve the Schema.org markup on a site, but I’m curious about a couple of things because of the content: webinars. See an example: https://www.brighttalk.com/webcast/667/83483

There are tens of thousands of webinars (and some videos) almost all of which are on-demand and therefore would seem to be clear-cut Video objects. The thing is, many of these webinars are scheduled well in advance and would seem (semantically) to be a live event, which would fall under the `Event` object category of Schema.org.

So I see three options:

- Tag everything as a Video
- Tag videos and on-demand webinars as Videos and upcoming webinars as Events
- Tag all videos as Videos and all webinars, upcoming and on-demand, as Events

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`EducationEvent`](http://schema.org/EducationEvent) is a more specific [`Event`](http://schema.org/Event), which may be appropriate for your case.

<del>`Event`/`EducationEvent` don’t define a property for specifying the actual "event" or the result of the event, probably because events typically happen in a [location](http://schema.org/location).</del> I guess the [`description`](http://schema.org/description) shouldn’t be used to include the video itself, as it’s defined as "*short* description *of* the item".

**Update**: There is the [`recordedIn` property](http://schema.org/recordedIn):

> The CreativeWork that captured all or part of this Event.

So you could use `EducationEvent` for the (live) webinar, and use `recordedIn` to reference the recording, in form of an [`VideoObject`](http://schema.org/VideoObject).